# How to make a UITabBarItem ignore the tintColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBar` with 5 tabs.

I set an "unselectedImage" to tabBarItem's `image` property and "selectedImage" to tabBarItem's `selectedImage` property.

The "selectedImage" is an image with a gradient, but it presents it in the color of the `tabBar.tintColor`.

So how can I cancel the `tintColor` and make the original image to be presented (without coloring it with the `tintColor`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the image, define the `rederingMode`:

```
yourUIImage.renderingMode = alwaysOriginal
```